# Do unnecessary for loop iterations affect speed?

Tags: javascript, optimization, for-loop

I have dynamic HTML with many `<div>`s that will have a class of `groupX` where `X` is a number between 1 and 100. I need to find out how many groups are in use to use elsewhere in the application and have this code at the moment:

```
for(i = 0; i <= 100; i++){                       
  if($j('.group' + i).size() > 0) {          
    totalAmountOfGroups++; 
  }
}
```

It works, though sometimes only 6 groups may be used, so I'm looping through 94 times unnecessarily and was wondering if this would affect speed (especially with the jQuery inside)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what is executed in the body of the `for`. The one in the question doesn't seem too pricey. However, I'd go for a different solution. When generating the HTML, you could add another class to the elements without the counter. E.g. `class="group group14"`. This way you could use a selector `$('.group')` so you would only iterate through the elements you need to.

Answer (score 2):

[Try like this](http://jsperf.com/jquery-vs-getelementsbyclassname)

It's not a good way, but faster than you approach. The best way is mark all elements by class 'group', and store group number in data attribute like data-group="n". After this you can select all elements by one operation, and than iterate selected elements to extract group number from attribute.

Comment: Thanks for the speed test, never thought about actually testing it. I did consider getElementsByClassName beforehand, but I need to support IE8 so it's not viable sadly

Answer (score 1):

You could add another class to your group , lets call it *grouped*, and then filter through them using a regex

```
var total = 0;
total = $('.grouped').filter(function(){
    return $(this).attr('class').match(/group[d+]/g);
}).size();
```

Comment: Marcells answer is a simpler version of mine :)